# Index.php/index.html files daily getting injected with include code

Tags: php, security

My site got hacked, updated from Drupal 7.3 to 7.59 after the issue occured for the security updates, but the issues are still coming up. Also I reverted the server to a state before the attack.

The server has had index files created daily, in weird places like css/js folders, but also in existing index.php/index.html, and these index files have this code in them:

```
<?PHP
 @include "\157\157\157\157\157\157\157\157\157\157\157\157";
```

I put the string (not this specific string) and the path is pointing to an ico file, but the ico file if you change from .ico to .php or .html or .txt, has a huge array

```
/*79026*/
<?PHP 
   @include some-folder-name/.81abc878.ico;

/*79026*/
```

I don't really understand the 79026, it's the same number on index.
The include path is a string of numbers/letters that I had to use https://www.unphp.net/ to decode due to it's format. My theory is that it's just intercepting post data and it's injecting that data into the .ico file which is actually a php script. I don't have access to that file, but if I do find it again I'll be sure to post an update.

Any help or guidance in fixing this would be great.

Comment: Did you update Drupal *after* the hack?

Comment: Restore from a backup from well before you noticed the issue.

Comment: I updated after the attack, yes. I also restored from a backup before the attack occurred. Still being generated.

Comment: Check all connections and permissions of files, ports, ftp, sftp, ssh, and change all passwords.

Comment: @ceejayoz super condescending 0 value response where the answer is in the question.

Comment: @Dave read the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall, the security issue was a remote code execution. That means they could have installed scripts on your server, and even modified your sshd to give them remote access.

Setup a new server, restore only drupal'd database, and reinstall drupal fresh, and with the already updated version. Then fix whatever's wrong with your website taking care not to copy files from the old server (other than media/images).

Hopefully that gets you in a clean state.

Comment: Did this happen to you? If it didn't could you give me more information on where you found out about this or read it? Thank you for the insight, we're in the process of moving servers to something more robust and secure.

Comment: did not happen to me. When you work in the infosec field, you see a lot of compromises boxes. If you are interested in this field, this is a good place to start: https://danielmiessler.com/blog/build-successful-infosec-career/